# Jest how to test if a mocked function is called

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, testing, mocking, jestjs

In my jest test I mock a service that i have made like this:

```
jest.mock("../../services/testService");
```

this works fine. Now I want to test if a mocked function was called how can is do this?

It tried to put the mock in a variable like this:

```
const fn = jest.mock("../../services/testService");
```

But when i do this i get errors because the test now refer to the real testservice and not the mocked one.

Can someone tell me how to test if a mocked function was called?

Comment: Provide the code you want to test.

Comment: @slideshowp2 have put the a function called testCall() in the mocked testService now I want to know if the testCall is called. you don`t need more code the i already have provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
//this is the key to know if a function has been called
const yourFunction = jest.fn() 
jest.doMock('../../services/testService', () => ({
  testService: {
    yourFunction
  },
}))
```

And then use the assertion on `yourFunction` to have been called.

EDIT:
I think this should work if you are trying to mock `react-native-push-notification`:

```
const localNotification = jest.fn() 
jest.doMock('react-native-push-notification', () => ({
  PushNotification: {
    configure: () => {},
    default: () => {},
    localNotification
  },
}))
```

Comment: hi @Ian Vasco I am trying to mock the Pushnotification of the react-native-push-notification module. I have tried it this way:

const yourFunction = jest.fn()

jest.doMock('react-native-push-notification', () => ({
  default: jest.fn(),
  configure: jest.fn(),
  localNotification: {yourFunction}
})); 

Als tried is without the brackets but does not work i want to know if LocalNotifcation was called

Comment: if i use your code i am getting the error:

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".